# How to modify the existing SQL connection in excel workbook using c# and then refresh the data

Tags: c#, sql, excel, vba, connection-string

I have Excel file which has SQL connection in workbook to fetch the data from SQL Server, I want to update the connection string using c# program but I am unable to get to the connection string value and can not update that. After first step I want to refresh the data for the same connection.
With the below code I am able to get the connection names but I am not able to find the way to modify it after that I can refresh the data with updated connection.

```
    private static void RefreshTheExcelData()
    {
        Application application_PMR = new Application();

        Workbook workbook_PMR = application_PMR.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

        var workBook_Connection = workbook_PMR.Connections;

        foreach (WorkbookConnection cn in workbook_PMR.Connections)
            Console.WriteLine(cn.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Are you not getting any value in `workbook_PMR.Connections`? Does any thing display on Console?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes in the console I am getting all the connection names (I have 4 connections) and getting them on console.

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to modify the connection string and then refresh the excel data with the connections. Here I am not able to get the connection string value and not getting a chance to modify the same.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.**WorkbookConnection**

Below I'm replacing the database server with a NEW database server.

It's not a console app but you get the idea.

### The code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

----
Excel.Workbook myBook = null;
Excel.Application myApp = null;
Excel.WorkbookConnection wbConn = null;
string workbook = @"C:\test\MCK VA User Level Security.xlsm";
string dbTarget = cboTarget.SelectedValue.ToString();
myApp = new Excel.Application();

try
{
    myApp.Visible = false;
    myBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(workbook);
    object index = 1 as object;
    for (int i = 1; i <= myBook.Connections.Count; i++)
    {
        wbConn = myBook.Connections.Item(i);
        dynamic dbConn = wbConn.OLEDBConnection.Connection;
        lblDataSource.Text = dbConn.Replace("oldDBserver", dbTarget); // display change
        dbConn = (object)lblDataSource.Text;
        wbConn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = dbConn; // Update the db connection string
    }
    myBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
    myBook.Save();

}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    myBook.Close(1);
    myApp.Quit();
    if (wbConn != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbConn); wbConn = null;
    if (myBook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myBook); myBook = null;
    if (myApp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myApp); myApp = null;
}
```